# Simplify $-8x - 12 + 3x - 5x + 9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I'm playing around with some maths, looking through my old algebra and calculus books and came upon this problem and so, I went through and simplified it or at least I believe I've simplified it correctly.

> Simplify $-8x - 12 + 3x - 5x + 9$

```
[(-8x - 12) + 3x] - 5x + 9                   order of operations
[-8x - (12 + 3x)] - 5x + 9                   associative property
     at [... - (12 + 3x)], i think this is identity property
[-8x - (3x + 12)] - 5x + 9                   commutative property
[-8x - 3x - 12] - 5x + 9
-11x - 12 - 5x + 9                           combine like terms
[(-11x - 12) - 5x] + 9                       order of operations
[-11x - (12 - 5x)] + 9                       associative property
[-11x - (-5x + 12)] + 9                      commutative property
-11x + 5x - 12 + 9
-6x - 12 + 9                                 combine like terms
-6x - 3                                      add
```

Is this the simplified answer -6x - 3 ?

Thanks,

Comment: It should be $-10x-3$. The only thing you need to do is, $(-8+3-5)x+(9-12)$.

Comment: ah, yes, even simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is in the second line:

$$(-8x-12x) +3x \neq -8x - (12x + 3x).$$
Addition associates, but subtraction does not: $(7-4)-3 = 0$, but $7-(4-3) = 7-1 = 6$.

The correct way to associate those terms is to remember that subtracting $12x$ is the same thing as adding $-12x$. So
$$(-8x - 12x) + 3x = \Bigl((-8x)+ (-12x)\Bigr) + 3x = -8x + \Bigl((-12x) + 3x)\Bigr) = -8x + (-12x + 3x)$$
or by being careful with the $-$ sign:
$$(-8x - 12x) + 3x = -8x - (12x - 3x)$$
(distribute the $-$ sign to see why they are equal).

Addition commutes and associates. All you need to do is consider the terms with $x$ together, and the constant terms together.

The terms with $x$ are $-8x$, $3x$, and $-5x$. When you add them together you get
$$-8x+3x-5x = (-8+3-5)x = -10x.$$

The constant terms are $-12$ and $9$. When you add them together you get $-3$. So the final answer is $-10x-3$.